# How do I access my angular scope from jQuery dialog buttons?

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rf0VItthVBg6j0z7KudO

I'm using a jQuery dialog and want to use the dialog buttons, but I don't know how to get at the scope to trigger a (currently non-existent) $http or $resource call back to the server with the updated model when the jQuery dialog button is clicked.  I feel as if I'm going about this wrong, but I don't know what direction to go here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Angular functions to find the scope attached to an element and call a function on it.  I prefer to really abstract it away and find the root of the `ng-app` and broadcast an event into the app so that the outside-code doesn't know about the specifics of the inside code except for the event that you broadcast.

```
angular.$externalBroadcast = function (selector, event, message) {
    var scope = angular.element(selector).scope();

    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.$broadcast(event, message);
    });
};
```

Then, from any code, you can call something like:

```
angular.$externalBroadcast('#app-container', 'doSomething', parameters);
```

And inside the app, I'd do something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('doSomething', function(parameters) {
    // handle the external event.
});
```

If you don't like this approach, just get the scope:

```
var scope = angular.element(selector).scope();
```

And do something with it.  Just make sure you call `scope.$apply` or else the digestion cycle won't happen.

Comment: In the above situation is there a way to get a factory or a directive scope?

Comment: Nvm. It seems that the scope you get is the rootScope. I attached the service to the root scope and was able to call it just how i needed. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to add directive to control. It is a bad idea to add jQuery with angularjs along side. Directive are made to do this kind of manipulation.

Here's I have modified your [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NRkw4rma8ghC3r28V55C?p=preview) to show you what you can do with directives.

```
app.directive('date', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     require: '^ngModel',
     link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
       var dp = $(elm);

       dp.datepicker({
         onSelect: function(dateText) {
           scope.$apply(function() { // Apply cause it is outside angularjs
            ctrl.$setViewValue(dateText); // Set new value of datepicker to scope
           });
        }
       });

       scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(nv) {
         dp.datepicker('setDate', nv); // Update datePicker date when scope change
       });
     }
  }
```

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the date picker and is all about the buttons you can add to the jQuery dialog being able to call a controller scope method.