# Re-run AngularJs Directive after jQuery plugin has manipulated the DOM

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom, jqgrid

In an AngularJS SPA application I'm using jqGrid plugin.
During the jqGrid bootsrap, on its "loadComplete" event I call a JQuery function which create and add an hyperlink on each row of the jqGrid. These hyperlinks uses "ng-href" to link to the related detail page:

```
<a ng-href="/detail/3">Detail 3</a>
```

After that, I run all the Angular js files and all the "ng-href" hyperlinks created before are correctly compiled.

When for istance I do an action in the jqGridUI, like going to page #2 or sort the grid by a specific column, jqGrid recreate the grid on the fly and I lost all the AngularJs "ng-ref" functionality.

Is there a way to tell AngularJS to re-compile the DOM of a specific HTML element (the jqGrid table in this case)?

Calling it at any jqGrid "loadComplete" event could be the correct way or maybe it would be better to have AngularJs that scan the DOM for changes any n seconds and recompile it if  the DOM has changed?

Comment: Have you tried to call `$scope.$apply()`? It is sometimes necessary when using third party plugins.

Comment: Following this article:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603855/how-do-i-access-my-angular-scope-from-jquery-dialog-buttons

I have correctly created a working angular.$externalBroadcast method that calls $scope.$apply(), but the modified HTML in the DOM is not corretcly recompiled and the ng-href are not working.

I cannot figure out how to tell AngularJS to recompile that modified HTML using the $compile method

Comment: I am not sure what the solution is. But it may be useful to check if it works if you wrap the part where jqGrid recreates the grid in $timeout(function(){ ... }, 50)

Comment: jqGrid recreates the grid internally